# iOS trigger Universal Link using openURL within the app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-universal-links

I want to trigger a Universal Link using `UIApplication.shared.open(url: )` but it always opens the browser.

I have this URL `https://example.com/path` and I followed all the steps to use it as an Universal Link for my App.

The Universal Link is working just fine, if I execute:

`xcrun simctl openurl booted "https://example.com/path"`

or if Tap in the URL in the reminder App, it redirects me perfectly.

Now I am getting the same URL from and endpoint within the app and I wish to redirect the user within the app.

This is my code

```swift
func handle(_ action: Action) {
   switch action {
   case .didTapAction(let actionURL):
    // actionURL = URL(string: "https://example.com/path")
    guard let url = actionURL else { return }
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
  }
}
```

Also I tried with

```swift
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [.universalLinksOnly: true])
```

But it never recognise the url as a Universal Link.

Is there a way to trigger a Universal Link that belongs to the same that is executing it from code?

Comment: Just use your URL routing logic to determine if it's a universal link to your own app and handle those URLs differently rather than using `open(url:)`.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @Martin, or did you end up following the suggestion from @Rudedog?

Comment: This must have been a fairly recent iOS change, as these types of links have been working for years in our app.

Comment: @simonki unfortunately I did not find any solution, I went with Rudedog solution